# Thinking-sphinx 3.0.5 broke Heroku Mysql connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

While running `bundle install` trying to update some other gem, Thinking Sphinx was updated to version 3.0.5 from 3.0.3.

I now get the following error on Heroku:

```
Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

Sphinx works fine locally, but any searches on Heroku result in this error. Of course, on Heroku it should not be attempting to connect to localhot but rather to the Sphinx add-on.

What changed in version 3.0.5 and how can I fix it?

Also, how can I protect my app against these kinds of things without staing forever in version 3.0.3?

Answer (score 0):

All the credit for this answer goes to Pat Allan, the creator of Thinking Sphinx, I'm just copying it here in the hopes that it will help someone else who encounters the issue:

The settings for the given environment (e.g. from config/thinking_sphinx.yml) are now reloaded when the Thinking Sphinx framework is configured (to re-apply any given values appropriately). However, Flying Sphinx sets the custom connection parameters into this settings hash in the Ruby side of things, and so those details are being lost and *not* re-applied (as they're not in the file).

```
The fix - at least for the moment - is as follows:

* In your Gemfile, set flying-sphinx's require to nil (so it's not loaded initially). 
* In your config/boot.rb file, add `require 'flying_sphinx/sinatra'` just after you switch Thinking Sphinx frameworks
```

Comment: Worth noting that this only happens when you're setting a new framework (which is likely only the case when using something other than Rails).